# Segmentation fault using scanf()

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, point

the code below compile well, but when i use it returns segmentation fault.

I was searching some similar errors in other topics, but i have not found much.

in case, thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double main( char *argv[]){
        FILE *ifp;
        double e,e_a,e_b,a,ct,b,sigma,tol;
        double Cla, theta;
        int n, nmax;

        ifp=fopen(argv[0],"r");
        scanf(ifp,"%lf %lf\n",&theta,&Cla);

        a=0.002;
        b=0.1;
        nmax=1000;
        ct=(a+b)/2;
        tol=0.00000001;

        sigma=0.14066;
        e_a=theta-(a*6/(sigma*Cla)+3/2*sqrt(a/2));
        e_b=theta-(b*6/(sigma*Cla)+3/2*sqrt(b/2));
        n=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems here.  First

```
scanf(ifp,"%lf %lf\n",&theta,&Cla);
```

You're calling `scanf` when you look like you want to use `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(ifp,"%lf %lf\n",&theta,&Cla);
```

Second is the file you're opening:

```
ifp=fopen(argv[0],"r");
```

`argv[0]` is the name of the running executable, which is probably not what you want.  If you want the first argument passed in, use `argv[1]`

```
ifp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Last is the definition of `main`:

```
double main( char *argv[]){
```

This is not a valid definition, as it should return an `int` and have both `argc` and `argv` or neither of them:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
```

You should also check that an argument was passed:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("missing argument\n");
    exit(1);
}
```